# Можно ли связать Python и С++ при помощи Qt?

Tags: python, c++, qt

Ну вот например мне надо вызвать Python-функцию из С++. Или наоборот. Могу ли я при помощи фреймворка Qt такое сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для встраивания в Qt C++ https://github.com/MeVisLab/pythonqt

Для встраивания в QML pyotherside

Также можно встраивать в C, а си встроить в qt https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/embedding.html